# Injected class name as type

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Given the following code,

```
template <class> using void_t = void;
template <class C, class = void> struct X { enum { v = 0 }; };
template <class C> struct X<C, void_t<typename C::T> > { enum { v = 1 }; };
struct T { };
int main() { return X<T>::v; }
```

what should main return?  GCC and MSVC say 1, Clang says 0.

Comment: Neat corner case. In other words: does the injected-class-name behave as an actual typedef?

Comment: This question arises from transparent comparators, classes that define a type member named `is_transparent`.  Is `struct is_transparent { };` transparent?.  We were surprised when compilers disagreed.

Comment: A well posed question would list and explain possible interpretations of a cryptic piece of code.

Comment: @n.m. [tag:language-lawyer] questions about which compiler is right are less about interpretations of the code than they are of the standard.

Answer (score 9):

I think Clang is right here. The rule in [[class.qual]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#class.qual-2) is:

> In a lookup in which function names are not ignored and the *nested-name-specifier* nominates a class `C`:
>
> - if the name specified after the *nested-name-specifier*, when looked up in `C`, is the *injected-class-name* of `C` ([class]), or
> - [... irrelevant here ...]
>
> the name is instead considered to name the constructor of class `C`. *[ Note:* For example, the constructor is not an acceptable lookup result in an *elaborated-type-specifier* so the constructor would not be used in place of the *injected-class-name*. *— end note ]* Such a constructor name shall be used only in the *declarator-id* of a declaration that names a constructor or in a using-declaration. *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A { A(); };
> struct B: public A { B(); };
>
> A::A() { }
> B::B() { }
>
> B::A ba;            // object of type A
> A::A a;             // error, A​::​A is not a type name
> struct A::A a2;     // object of type A
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

`typename C::T` is the same kind of thing as `A::A`, it's lookup in which function names are not ignored (`typename` doesn't cause function names to be ignored). So, in `typename C::T`, when `C` is `T`, the name `T` is considered to name the constructor. As it's not a type name, we should get a substitution failure and fallback to the primary template.

Filed [86818](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=86818).

Comment: "(`typename` doesn't qualify here as not ignoring function names)" -- isn't there a typo here?

Comment: @Quentin What's the typo?

Comment: Double negation as I understand -- it says that `typename` qualifies as ignoring function names.

Comment: @Quentin It's not double negation.

Comment: Then I just don't understand that sentence :)

Comment: @Quentin. Let `X` be "not ignoring function names." The sentence is: `typename` doesn't qualify for  `X`. That's not double negation, it's not qualifying for something. Double negation would be something like... "`typename` doesn't fail to qualify for `X`". It might also help to think of `X` instead of as "only considering type names".

Comment: @Quentin He's saying that the use of `typename` doesn't stop lookup from ignoring function names (i.e constructors). That's why `typename C::T` names a constructor and why it causes a substitution failure.

Comment: @0x499602D2 No, it's the use of `typename` doesn't cause lookup to ignore function names.

Comment: That's way more understandable (I'm still confused by the first version but whatever). But more importantly, *why* doesn't `typename` ignore function names? And actually, why can we name a constructor at all when it's impossible to do anything with it?

Comment: @T.C.Sorry that's what I meant to say. :)

Comment: For the curious about template name resolution in the precesence of typename [\[temp.res\]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#4) *The usual qualified name lookup is used to find the qualified-id even in the presence of typename.*

Answer (score 5):

To complete Barry's answer, `typename` only says to the compiler that the following name is a type for the analysis performed before template instatiation. After instantiation, name look up is performed as if typename was not there, [[temp.res]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.res#4):

> The *usual qualified name lookup* is used to find the qualified-id *even in the presence of typename*.

So Clang is right. In order to get a consistent compiler behaviour you can use the [elaborated type specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.type.elab#nt:elaborated-type-specifier) `struct C::T` in place of `typename C::T`:

```
template <class> using void_t = void;
template <class C, class = void> struct X { enum { v = 0 }; };
template <class C> struct X<C, void_t<struct C::T> > { enum { v = 1 }; };
struct T { };
int main() { return X<T>::v; }
```